# PHP group_concat inserting seperator or order by results in no data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that works with no separator and no order by code which is here

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT PlayerName, GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber)
FROM BallotNumbers
GROUP BY PlayerName') as $row) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PlayerName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

which results in

__Angel_
980,979,981,982,983
But if i change this code

```
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT PlayerName, GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber)
```

to

```
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT PlayerName, GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber SEPARATOR ', ')
```

i get No data available in table and if i add a order by the page wont access at all any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are using the same quote to quote the PHP string as well as to quote the MySQL string within the PHP string.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT has a max length, just saying.  Once I had it silently truncating my data, wasn't pleasant figuring that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aliases for proper result:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT PlayerName, GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber SEPARATOR ', ') as bn FROM BallotNumbers GROUP BY PlayerName");
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PlayerName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['bn'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

**UPD** from @apokryfos comment

Comment: using an alias for the resulting column is an improvement but doesn't solve the actual problem ... which is in fact the use of the same quote delimiter

Comment: @Blablaenzo I've updated my answer, thx to @apokryfos. There was error too, because he used `GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber)` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT(BallotNumber SEPARATOR ', ')` as array key